# javascript framework for building os x apps

Tags: javascript, macos, osx-lion

Is there a javascript framework that lets me build os x apps?

I would like to build os x apps using javascript. I was wondering if there a bridge language like MacRuby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - http://www.appcelerator.com/